# C++ Overloading/Matching N nested templates

Tags: c++, templates

I am attempting to handle nested templates in c++ and am not even sure if this is possible. The point of this is to compile time type check n-th order derivatives. The following code is just an example of some more complicated stuff I am trying to do, but solving the following will extrapolate. Here is my base case:

```
struct XAxis {};
struct YAxis {};

template<typename T>
class Deriv {
    public:
        double a;
        Deriv(double in_a) : a(in_a) {};
}

template<>
class Deriv<XAxis> {
    public:
        double a;
        Deriv(double in_a) : a(in_a) {};
        double x() {
            return a;
        }
}

template<>
class Deriv<YAxis> {
    public:
        double a;
        Deriv(double in_a) : a(in_a) {};
        double y() {
            return a;
        }
}
```

The following then works:

```
Deriv<XAxis> xvel{1.0};
std::cout << xvel.x() << std::endl;
```

I then want to be able to do the following, but I'm not sure how to implement it:

```
Deriv<Deriv<YAxis>> yacc{1.0};
std::cout << yacc.y() << std::endl;
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what the exact behaviour you're looking for is.

Comment: Pretty much exactly what StoryTeller answered. Need to check but it looks right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to me that a partial specialization should do what your simplified example is after

```
template<typename T>
class Deriv<Deriv<T>> : public Deriv<T> {
    public:
        Deriv(double in_a) : Deriv<T>(in_a) {};
};
```

That should handle arbitrary nested `Deriv` specializations. Adding the above is enough to make your test case compile, which I assumed is the stated goal.

Comment: Oh the extend makes so much sense. I was really overlooking that!